# VBA: The referenced object no loger exist in the document

Tags: vba, coreldraw

In the loop the first three commands are successfull. 
But not the forth line of the loop - there is an error there.
We are able to set up properties for outlineShape an s but what's wrong with weld?

```
Dim outlineShape As Shape
Dim weldShape As Shape

For Each s In sr

        Set outlineShape = s.Outline.ConvertToObject
        outlineShape.Fill.UniformColor.CMYKAssign 100, 0, 0, 0
        s.Fill.UniformColor.CMYKAssign 0, 0, 0, 50

        ' Set weldShape = outlineShape.Weld(s)    ' error here! Method Weld of object IDrawShape failed
        ' in debagger, the line shows: The referenced object no loger exist in the document

Next s
```

Comment: `Weld` is not a member of the `Shape` object, and neither is `Outline` as far as I can see.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193908.

Comment: @CBRF23 it's coreldraw not excel

Comment: Sorry, was late last night. I can't find coreldraw's object model reference online.  I found their intro to using VBA, which is very nicely put together, but doesn't describe the weld method anywhere that I could see.

Comment: These operations can be done in the UI without VBA.  If you take the object which this operation fails on, and manually convert the outline to an object, then weld the two together, what happens?  A sufficiently complex weld or outline to object operation can fail in CorelDraw, and I'm uncertain what would happen to if a complex weld was attempted within a VBA macro.

Answer (score 0):

Work fine with corel x6.

```
Sub test()
    Dim outlineShape As Shape
    Dim weldShape As Shape
    Dim s As Shape

    For Each s In ActiveDocument.ActiveLayer.Shapes

            Set outlineShape = s.Outline.ConvertToObject
            outlineShape.Fill.UniformColor.CMYKAssign 100, 0, 0, 0
            s.Fill.UniformColor.CMYKAssign 0, 0, 0, 50

            Set weldShape = outlineShape.Weld(s)    
    Next s


End Sub
```

Try to declare s as Shape and your `sr` change to "shape array". 
I think the proplem is that your `sr` object is not a type such as you need.